# Swipe Gesture With Object IOS

Tags: ios

I am looking to create something similar to the iPhone lock screen. I would like the user to be able to drag a button revealing a textview. I would just like some general guidance of how I would go about doing this. Would I use a swipe gesture? A drag button.... I am looking for a realistic spring motion.

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create gesture handle view on top of the control and place button and textview under it as subview. and add swipe gesture to gestureView and trigger dragging button function when it detected the gesture and show the text view..

Comment: is there a way to do it so it doesn't just move off the label but is like a real drag so if the person lets go it will spring back